# ¿Se podría añadir un favicon con react, de la pagina web, a un enlace proveniente de otra pagina/servidor?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

No tengo mucha experiencia con react, y necesito saber si es posible agregar el favicon de mi pagina a un enlace proveniente del servidor, en el momento en que se redirige a él y se abre el archivo que se desea visualizar, el servidor que estamos usando es aws .

Y no sé si es posible agregar un favicon a un enlace que provenga de otra pagina. Lo único que puedo encontrar de momento, son las formas de agregar un favicon a tu propia página web y eso ya lo tengo :(

Espero que entiendan mi pregunta, porque es difícil para mí explicarlo exactamente, ¡pero agradecería tu ayuda!

[image: Esta seria una captura del enlace donde redirecciona al abrir el archivo, y es aquí donde debo agregar el favicon en caso de que se pueda]

Answer (score 0):

Todos tus componentes de React se renderizan en un `<div />` que está en el archivo `public/index.html` dentro de tu proyecto de React.

Así que si necesitas agregar un favicon en todas tus páginas, bastaría con ponerlo solo en ese HTML para que se vea en toda tu App.

También se puede poner el link de un favicon de un sitio externo a tu proyecto de esa manera.

Para hacerlo, se usa la etiqueta de HTML `<link rel="icon">`.

Por ejemplo:

```
 <link rel="icon" href="LINK DEL FAVICON QUE VIENE DE OTRO SITIO WEB" />
```

Comment: hola! gracias por tu respuesta, nada mas quería aclarar que, en este caso, soy yo quien debo agregar el favicon de mi pagina a otra, en el momento en que se redirecciona a ella, este link proviene del servidor que usamos para subir nuestros archivos, y quisiéramos que al momento de que el usuario abra el enlace, también le aparezca el icono de la pagina allí. Así como mencionas, tenemos el index.html que se encarga de mostrar en toda la app, pero no aplica a este enlace que comento.

Comment: Ah, recién ahora entiendo bien tu pregunta. Bueno, ahí te paso otra pregunta en inglés en donde se responde eso mismo: [Favicon for Amazon s3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28594514/favicon-for-amazon-s3-bucket). A ver si eso te ayuda.